# Cannot convert Sydney to Brisbane LocalDateTime in Java8

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

Trying to convert String date which is in Australia/Sydney to Australia/Brisbane. I want this in Java8 using LocalDateTime

I have tried with date and works fine but date is deprecated.

```
    String sdate = "2019-01-14T01:42:00.19+11:00";

    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Australia/Brisbane"));
    try {
        Date  dd = format.parse(sdate);
        DateFormat teradataFormate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        System.out.println(teradataFormate.format(dd));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //Code that doesn't work with LocalDateTime 
     String sdate = "2019-01-14T01:42:00.19+11:00";

    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(sdate, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"));
    ZonedDateTime brisy = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Australia/Brisbane"));
    DateTimeFormatter format1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(format1.format(brisy));
```

expected : 2019-01-14 00:42:00
actual :2019-01-14 01:42:00

Answer (score 4):

1. Use ZonedDateTime instead of LocalDateTime. LocalDateTime doesn't support daylight savings.
2. Use withZoneSameInstant() intead of withZoneSameLocal

   ```
   ZonedDateTime sydneyTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(sdate);
   ZonedDateTime brisyTime = sydneyTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Australia/Brisbane"));
   DateTimeFormatter format1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   System.out.println(brisyTime.format(format1));
   ```

Comment: Nicely explained and elegant answer, thanks. Since `sdate` contains an offset (`+11:00`) and no time zone (like `Australia/Sydney`), a further minor improvement is to parse into an `OffsetDateTime` and then use its `atZoneSameInstant` method.

Comment: Amazing. It worked with offsetDateTime. Thanks for clearing me the difference between Offset and timezone.